# removeFromSuperView not working on button

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

Another issue I'm breaking my head to.
I've created a UIButton programmatically. It's sole purpose is to stand on top of another button that has been pushed for half a second. The bottom button is a picture, the top button is a trashcan. You can see what I'm trying to do here: I have a picture, and to delete it you have to push it for a while.

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.capturedImageOneSmall.frame, tapAndHoldPoint)) {

                aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan = [[UIButton alloc] init];
                aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan.frame = self.capturedImageOneSmall.frame;
                [aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LogoTrashcan"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan.tag = 1;
                [self.scrollView addSubview:aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan];
```

When I call my method to delete both buttons, only the picture goes, the trashcan stays and is even still tappable.

```
- (void)deleteImage:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan.tag == 1) {
        [self.capturedImageOneSmall removeFromSuperview]; //this works!
        self.capturedImageOneSmall = nil;
        capturedImageOneData = nil;
    }
    [aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; //this doesn't!
    aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan = nil;
```

You guys have any idea?

Comment: It is probably setting it to nil before remove from super view, but to be sure, try it without the performSelector to see if it disappears.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @afonso. But I tried everything like [aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan removeFromSuperview], just setting it to nil, trying to use aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan.hidden = YES,... It just stays there.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help. But, just one more thing, your aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan, is an instance variable, right? Why, and how, are you calling it directly? Shouldn't that be self.aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan ? Or, in the delete method, sender?

Comment: Yeh, sorry about that. Changed it now. Still no progress though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show the output of this statement, when you place it right before the line that contains the 'performSelectorOnMainThread' call:

```
NSLog(aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan: %@, aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, it's the world cup and Belgium won yesterday :) The output says: 2014-07-02 11:11:40.523 Wheels[5022:60b] self.aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan, <UIButton: 0x14575090; frame = (3091 50; 160 120); alpha = 0.5; opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1459bfe0>>

Comment: Allright, so looking at that frame, it seems your label is not even visible to begin with, so removing will also be unnoticeable. It also means that you are not sending there removeFromSuperview to an object you see on screen (as the frame's x-origin is 3091 which is most likely offscreen). Please show the code where 'aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan' gets assigned (i.e. "aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan = [UIVIew alloc] init];" or something like that).

Comment: That's the point, my app has a +5000 pixel horizontal `scrollView`. I can see the button, it's where it's supposed to be at 3091x. You can see the allocation of the button in my top question. Thanks

Comment: Where is aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan declared? Are you sure the object allocated is the same one that is receiving the removeFromSuperview message? Can you print them both out using NSLog to see if their memory-addresses are the same?

Comment: It is declared in my .h file: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan;` Only one object I think.

Comment: We need to be sure. Can you log the object right after you alloc/init it and show the output here? I am suspecting that you have one object coming from interface builder, and then you create another label and assign it to aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan. This way, you might have two labels on the same place, so removing one will be invible, as another one is below it. And since you have no more (direct) reference to the label from interface-builder it is hard to make that one disappear. But please, show the output of logging both the one you logged before and the one right after it is allocated.

Comment: `2014-07-02 12:40:45.702 Wheels[5258:60b] allocated self.aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan: <UIButton: 0x15eb5e80; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15eb1870>>` and 
`2014-07-02 12:40:45.961 Wheels[5258:60b] allocated self.aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan: <UIButton: 0x15eb7940; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15eb6560>>` Bro, I think you're on to something. Why are there Two buttons being allocated??

Comment: See my answer I just added.

Comment: `2014-07-02 12:50:54.442 Wheels[5285:60b] allocated self.aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan: <UIButton: 0x15deef20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15dec530>>` and 
`2014-07-02 12:50:54.585 Wheels[5285:60b] allocated self.aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan: <UIButton: 0x15ea4620; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15ea0ce0>>` this one will be removedFromSuperView -->
`2014-07-02 12:50:55.323 Wheels[5285:60b] self.aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan, <UIButton: 0x15ea4620; frame = (3091 50; 160 120); alpha = 0.5; opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x15ea0ce0>>`

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much! I found out that `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` gets called twice. Once it has begun and once it has ended. I had no idea! Now I added `if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)`. Only one button gets allocated now and everything works like I want it to! Wauw again, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see that they have different memory addresses? (0x15eb5e80 and 0x15eb7940). I am suspecting that you have one object coming from interface builder, and then you create another label and assign it to aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan. This way, you might have two labels on the same place, so removing one will be invible, as another one is below it. And since you have no more (direct) reference to the label from interface-builder it is hard to make that one disappear.

So if you leave out the alloc/init line, I suspect your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:? It makes no sense (at least not without additional context).
Anyway, you specify NO for waituntildone, so it means this work is scheduled to be done at the end of the runloop, by which time you already have aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan to nil.

If for some reason you really want to make this removeFromSuperView happen at the end of the runloop, simply dispatch it to the mainqueue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [aboutToDeleteImageTrashCan removeFromSuperview];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I started with a simple removeFromSuperView, tried all kinds of stuff to get the button to disappear, but no luck. The performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: was my last try. BTW, your answer doesn't remove it either.